# How to store a php variable with spaces into a html variable?

Tags: php, html

I have a php array element that would like to submit as a POST value but it is only accepting the first word due to the spacings. Below is my source code :

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter the amount to order" size="5" name='.$row["fname"].' />
```

When the page is printed it shows as :

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter the amount to order" size="5" name=Mussel in Chill Sauce />
```

As you can see, only the word "Mussel" was stored into the `name` variable of the html form. How do i store the full text "Mussel in chilli sauce" which is derived from my `$row["fname"]`?

Appreciate your help thanks

Comment: `name="' . $row["fname"] . '" />'`. Or use `printf()` instead. Also, by the way, `name` is an *attribute*, not an HTML variable. HTML doesn't have variables.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: name is attribute for HTML tag. All attributes in HTML should be in double quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap them in quotes properly:

```
echo '
    <input 
        type="number" 
        class="form-control" 
        placeholder="Please enter the amount to order" 
        size="5" 
        name="'.$row["fname"].'" />
';
```

Sidenote: Thats not a good name value, are you sure thats the value you want? You should consider putting other name value instead as this would look like inside the `$_POST` variable when its submitted:

```
Array
(
    [Mussel_in_Chill_Sauce] => 1 // going to access this thru $_POST['Mussel_in_Chill_Sauce'] ?
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code `name="'.$row["fname"].'"`

Answer (score 0):

Put quotes around attribute values with spaces in them.

For that matter, put quotes around all attribute values. They are sometimes optional and never forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

I think that way to do will help you :).

```
name="'.$row["fname"].'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this to have `name` inside double-quotes

```
 <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter the amount to order" size="5" `name="'.$row[fname']." />`
```